# Is there any conflict between app pool's Start Mode and Idle timeout action?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I would like to keep the server running (alive) all the day (at least to the midnight when it can be recycled by scheduling) so I've found that setting `Start Mode` to `AlwaysRunning` can help achieve this. But still there is another option which seems to confict with that `AlwaysRunning`, that is `Idle Timeout Action`.

The `Idle Timeout` is still kept at the default value of `20` minutes, but the `Idle Timeout Action` is set to `Terminate`. So I'm not really sure if which setting takes over the other? In this case I think the `Start Mode` should override the `Idle Timeout Action`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the user reports in this [thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/522), idle time out will be honored even when StartMode=AlwaysRunning. But also according to that thread, this contradicts some Microsoft documentation, so it might be a bug and not designed behavior.  So your experiences may vary depending on which version of the product you're using.  Looks like the best thing to do is to set Idle Timeout to 0.

Comment: yes without setting idle timeout to 0, it won't work. Also there is another setting that may recycle the app pool at the wrong time you may not expect, the default cycling interval is about 29 hours, so I removed it and set a fixed time when it should recycle (about 1-2 hours passing mid-night).